# How can I control empty JSON

Tags: android, json, post, get

I read JSON from server and sent post to server for delete.

if my JSON is equal this, it is not problem. I can parse.

{"tables":[{"id":"1","number":"4"},{"id":"2","number":"1"},{"id":"3","number":"2"},{"id":"4","number":"3"}]}

however, if my SJON is empty after post for delete like this,

[]

I can not parse because it is empty,it is give exception and app doesn't run. I want to control if it is empty, don't read.

```
final String TAG_CONTACTSORDERS = "tables";
...
.....
try{
contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTSORDERS);  //this line give error
....
...
```

thank you;

Comment: What exception? How are you parsing it? Please post a stack trace of the problem and your parsing code where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("");
Scanner oku = new Scanner(url.openStream());
while (oku.hasNextLine())
    data = oku.nextLine();
    if(!data.equals("[]"))
    {
      ....
      ...
      ..
```

I solved problem thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple possible solutions:

1. Catch the Exception thrown when parsing and handle accordingly.
2. (*Hackier solution*) Check the length of the returned String before parsing it. If it's less than "tables".length (*ie. 5*), you know you're not going to be able to parse it and should handle accordingly.